# Using JSON object for php login

Tags: php, html, json

I'm creating a login page for my website.

I have a php script which has a login function (with database query and required login information), I got able to convert the php call into a JSON object like this:

```
{"username":"blabla","password":"bla"}
```

Now I have a `login.php` script with username and password fields using html tags.

```
<form action="<?php echo MY_URL; ?>" id="login-form" class="smart-form client-form">
    <header>Sign In</header>
    <fieldset>
        <section>
            <label class="label">E-mail</label>
            <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
            <input type="email" name="email">
            <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right"><i class="txt-color"></i> Please enter username</b></label>
        </section>

        <section>
            <label class="label">Password</label>
            <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append lock"></i>
            <input type="password" name="password">
            <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right"><i class="txt-color"></i> Enter your password</b> </label>
            <div class="note">
                <a href="<?php echo MY_URL; ?>/forgotpassword.php">Forgot password?</a>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section>
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" checked="">
                <i></i>Stay signed in</label>
        </section>
    </fieldset>
    <footer>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
    </footer>
</form>
```

Can anybody tell me how to use above JSON object for the login part in my `login.php` script?

Comment: That isn't JSON and I can't think of any reason to use JSON for this at all.

Comment: are your trying to do login through ajax.Still not clear what you want to do.

Comment: I dont have much ajax knowledge, is there anyway i could use the passed {username,password} for my php login script. I wouldnt mind using any technology or plugin.. to be precise i want my login.php to use the data that is passed as username and password

Comment: Search the google for either AJAX or XHR.

Comment: All you have here is a login form. Do you have a processing script and a database set up for users? If you don't know how to proceed passed the form, I highly recommend that you do not attempt to create a login yourself if its for a real website. There are serious security considerations that go way beyond simple scripts to check a user username & password in a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ajax for this , it's much better than what you are trying to do ..

add id for a submit button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="login_submit">
```

add ids for email & the password tex fields

```
 <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
 <input type="password" name="password" id="password">

<script>
    //after the user click admin login button
    $('#login_submit').live('click',function()
    {
        var form_data = {
                        email: $('#email').val(),
                        password: $('#password').val(),
                    };

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "login.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data : form_data,
                cache:false,
                success: 
                    function(data){
                        console.log(data);


                        if(data.validation_result == "passed" )
                        {
                            alert(' You are successfully log in .. ' );
                        }

                        else if( data.registration == "falied" ){
                            alert('please enter a correct email & password');
                            }

                        else{

                            //if the user name is wrong this will alert the error message
                            if(data.username){

                                alert('email is wrong');
                            }

                            //if the password is wrong this will alert the error message
                            if(data.password){
                                alert('password is wrong');

                            }
                        }
                    }

                });

        return false;   
    });
</script>
```

& in your login.php you can add like this

```
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $pass = $_POST['password'];

  //do your validation here 
  if( validation ok ) { echo '{"validation_result": "passed"}'; }
  else{ echo '{"registration" : "falied"}'; }
```

Hope this will help you ...